# How to set default virtual server (sites-available) in Apache?

Tags: apache

I have 2 sites at my linode VPS. I configured ourdomain.com and mydomain.com in sites-available directory (/etc/apache2/sites-available/ourdomain.com.conf // mydomain.com.conf) and activated and restarted Apache.

There is a way to specify ourdomain.com as the main/default site? Because when I access through the ip, Apache shows mydomain.com :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost 172.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 172.0.0.1:80>
ServerName www.ourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /www/ourdomain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>
```

---

replace `172.0.0.1` with your IP

I hope this will help you.

Comment: please add some explanation as well in your answer.

Comment: users don't want to add each time 8080. It's better to use the config outside the virtualhosts to set the default server. It means to comment the virtualhost tags around the main domain name

Answer (score 0):

By default, the entries (symlinks) in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` are read in alphanumeric order. To change the order, simply go to that directory and rename the symlinks the way you want, `mv ourdomain.com.conf 0-ourdomain.com.conf` and do `service apache2 reload` to activate the change.